# Atomically modify int value

Tags: java, multithreading, integer

Googling for ABA-problem that may appear when using `CompareAndSwap`-like `Read-Modify-Write` instruction set I found `Load-Linked/Store-Conditional` ***lock-free*** approach to that problem.

So, I tried to implement `LL/SC` for ints using just `CAS`-set of instruction.

```
public class LlscInteger {
    private static final Unsafe U = getUnsafe();
    private static final long VALUE_OFFSET;
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> linkTracker;
    private volatile int value;

    public int loadLinked(){
        return value;
    }

    public boolean storeConditional(int newVal){
        //...
    }

    //Unsafe mechanics
}
```

The problem is I cannot update `value` and `linkTracker` atomically. Looking at C++11 `std::atomic` I also didn't find something similar to `LL/SC`. `sun.misc.Unsafe` does not contain `LL/SC` either.

***QUESTION:*** Is it possible to implement `LL/SC` via `CAS`? If so, can you give me some advice?

I don't see how LL/SC would be possible to implement just using `volatile`. The store conditional would like like the following:

```
public boolean storeConditional(int newVal){
    if(//the value is not changed since the loadLinked call){
        value = newValue
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to accomplish.  LL/SC seems to desire atomic updating only if nothing else is writing to it, which is effectively what `volatile` will let you do.  Was there something more *specific* that you were aiming for?

Comment: @Makoto Can you look at some update?

Comment: Why not use an Immutable Class that holds  "Value" and "linkTracker" and update the values in one go.
Or lock these two invariants "value" and linkTracker with one lock and update atomically?

Comment: @Timothy Because it will not be lock-free in that case. My bad I didn't specify in in the question.

Comment: Ahh just saw your edit,  by definition compare-and-swap is compound operation , i think there is a jvm instruction for atomic increment , not sure about java lang.

Comment: @Timothy There is an atomic CAS instruction on most architectures. For instance `Unsafe::compareAndSwapInt` is equivalent to C++11 `std::compare_and_exchange_strong`.